# Identifying an Instrument

Tags: python, music

Say I have a file that contains a single musical instrument, how can I use python code to detect which instrument is it (ultimate goal), or at least what is the category of instruments it belongs to (such as wind instruments)?
What are the steps I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I use python code

Since Python is Turing-complete, as are every pretty much anything else called a "programming language", there's not much special about it beyond its convenience and popularity.  There's no point in dwelling on the "Python-ness" of the problem -- you need to understand the math and the signal processing, and how to take *any* math and write code in *any* language -- then you apply that to Python specifically.

> to detect which instrument is it

Probably using convolutional neural networks and deep learning.  But that's a big subject that'll take a lot of studying -- years, unless you're already trained or thoroughly self-taught in computer science.

Basically, the architecture of a system like that is some sort of pre-processing (i.e. a filter bank, or some wavelet processing, or time-frequency filtering) to reduce the data down to what you think is probably important.  Then that's run into a neural network, and you find a bazillion samples to train the network *on* to distinguish what instrument is being played.